# React and Github Pages - my homepage isnt defaulting to home page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, github-pages

The pages and everything are displaying correctly, it's just that the landing page itself isn't the actual homepage of the website. If you need any more information, just ask me for more information. Also I tried using `HashRouter` because I read that it might be a good solution over `BrowserRouter`

**Index**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <HashRouter>
      <App />
    </HashRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**App**

```
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import { HashRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css';
import Services from './components/pages/Services'
import Gallery from './components/pages/Gallery'
import About from './components/pages/About'
import ContactUs from './components/pages/ContactUs'
import Interior from './components/pages/Interior'
import Exterior from './components/pages/Exterior'
import DoorTrim from './components/pages/DoorTrim'
import DecksFences from './components/pages/DecksFences'
import Home from './components/pages/Home'
import SimpleSlider from "./components/SimpleSlider";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home />} exact />
          <Route path='/services'  element={<Services />} />
          <Route path='/gallery'  element={<Gallery />} />
          <Route path='/about'  element={<About />} />
          <Route path='/contact-us'  element={<ContactUs />} />
          <Route path='/interior'  element={<Interior />} />
          <Route path='/exterior'  element={<Exterior />} />
          <Route path='/door-trim-painting'  element={<DoorTrim />} />
          <Route path='/decks-fences'  element={<DecksFences />} />
        </Routes>
      
        <SimpleSlider />
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "homepage": "https://github.com/aero8991/summit-view-painting",
  "name": "paint-site",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "firebase": "^9.15.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.6.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy" : "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: What page is being displayed instead?

Comment: What is the "landing page" and what is the "home page"?

Comment: @vr. I think just goes to a generic blank page. Each one of the Route paths goes to its own unique page and in those pages all contain some sort of return html. This is happening when I click on the homepage link  that I setup in pacakge.json using my repo.

Comment: @DrewReese Those should be the same.  <Route path='/' element={<Home />} exact />

Comment: Sorry, then I think I have the same question as @vr., what is the entry point URL/path and what is getting rendered? Can you [edit] to include your package.json file, and link us to your app running in github?

Comment: Try taking the `basename="/#"` off the `Router`. Do you have this app running live via github yet?

Comment: It is running live. I tried removing the hash and still not going to the home page. You can view the link here: https://aero8991.github.io/summit-view-painting/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252393/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-aero8991).